# getting only one of the values from call

Tags: racket

Is there a way to only get one of the results returned from `values`? I tried doing `(define x (first (values 1 2)))` but that didn't work. Is the only way to write something like `(define-values (x dont-care) (values 1 2))` and define an extra variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the only way to write something like `(define-values (x dont-care) (values 1 2))` and define an extra variable?

The only ways to get one of the values out of a multiple-valued thing all involve defining extra variables like `dont-care` here. However, you can use scoping, either local-scope or macro-scope, to mitigate this and hide them away.

You can use `let-values` to limit the scope like this:

```
(define x (let-values ([(x dont-care) (values 1 2)]) x))
```

Or you can use a macro to "hide" the other variables:

```
(define-syntax-rule (define-first-of-two-values x expr/2vs)
  (define-values (x dont-care) expr/2vs))

(define-first-of-two-values x (values 1 2))
```

After this definition `x` will be available, but `dont-care` will not because its limited to the scope of the macro definition.

You can also use an existing macro such as [`match-define-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match-define-values%29%29), with the `_` wildcard for the values you don't care about.

```
(match-define-values (x _) (values 1 2))
```

The `match-define-values` macro actually expands into something very similar to the first `let-values` example above.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps an unrelated question: is multiple-values the best way to implement a function that returns multiple things? Or is it better to use things like pairs? (with the advantage that the returned values can be manipulated using `car` and `cdr`)

Comment: Multiple-values are definitely less flexible than data such as pairs, tuples, or lists. There have been many times where I've chosen to return a fixed-length list instead of multiple values, especially if I want to have something either succeed with multiple values, or fail with a single value `#f`. Patterns like that don't go well with `values` returns, but fixed-length lists are more flexible.

Comment: @JRR While Scheme multiple values probably are faster than CL it is far less usable. In CL you can always use every function that returns multiple values and it will use only the first outside of a `multiple-value-bind` (same as Scheme `let-values`).

Comment: Thanks both. I was trying to look for the equivalent of python's "parallel assignment" in racket and I stumbled upon this. Not sure if this is the right thing to do?

Comment: Pattern matching, from `racket/match`

Comment: @AlexKnauth example? not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this macro:

```
(define-syntax-rule (first-value expr)
  (call-with-values (λ () expr)
    (λ (result . ignored) result)))

> (first-value (values 10 20 30 40 50))
10
```

This works with any number of values. See [`call-with-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html?q=call-with-values#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-values%29%29) for documentation.